# Symfony crud edict : Could not load type "datetime"

Tags: php, datetime, symfony

**Context:**

I create a project with symfony 3. My database have one table with a field *datetime*

With this commands I create a simple CRUD application for one table

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force adminBundle xml

php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src

php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities adminBundle

php bin/console generate:doctrine:crud
```

**Error:**

So  my crud is done but when I edit one row throw an error

> Could not load type "datetime" 500 Internal Server Error -
>   InvalidArgumentException

Stack Trace

```
  in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Form/FormRegistry.php at line 87
```

I think  that could not load type “datetme”, I try register my form in the section services of my services.yml, but I don't know How to do it? for the type datetime.

Any idea? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Seems like a bug in the CRUD generator. It uses a type alias instead of the fully qualified class name:

```
$builder->add('fieldName', 'textarea');
```

The fully qualified class name is required since Symfony 3.0:

```
$builder->add('fieldName', DateTimeType::class);
```

Please check the generated form type.

Comment: Thank you! Seems like the symfony 3 generator is not using the FQCN automatically.... It's a bug. Going to report that :)

Comment: What is full namespace of DatetimeType?

Comment: Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType

Comment: Don't forget the use statement or you will still have issues

Comment: So how to fix this bug in CRUD generator? The path to look at is `src/YourBundle/Form`.

Answer (score 2):

Sergey, thanks for pointing that out. I'm not sure why, but specifying the fully qualified class name didn't resolve the issue on my end. Removing the datetime alias all together did.

**Changed:**

```
$builder
  ->add('name')
  ->add('time', 'datetime')
  ->add('location')
;
```

**To:**

```
$builder
  ->add('name')
  ->add('time')
  ->add('location')
;
```

Comment: Try to import DateTime class first
"use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;"

and then

"$builder->add('time', DateTimeType::class)"

Answer (score -1):

symfony 3.0v
php 5.6v

> Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\DateTimeType;
>
> ->add('perfecnacimiento', DateTimeType::class)

Comment: Good answers on StackOverflow should include an explanation, not just code.